# Unable to create GridSpace Object in SynapseML

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a GridSpace object in SynapseML , like this

```
paramGrid = HyperparamBuilder().addHyperparam(gbt,gbt.maxBin, DiscreteHyperParam([200, 255,300]))
searchSpace= paramGrid.build()
print(searchSpace)
type(searchSpace)
GridSpace(searchSpace)
```

This gives me the following error
P

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.automl.GridSpace. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.automl.GridSpace([class [Lscala.Tuple2;]) does not exist
```

When I ran the code to instantiate a RandomSpace object it worked properly.
I checked the api docs of the 2 constructors here
https://mmlspark.blob.core.windows.net/docs/0.10.1/pyspark/_modules/synapse/ml/automl/HyperparamBuilder.html#DiscreteHyperParam

For GridSpace:

```
def __init__(self, paramValues):
```

And for RandomSpace:

```
def __init__(self, paramDistributions):
```

I saw both the params are unpacked in the same way , so I am not able to figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import the necessary modules and try below code:**

```
>from synapse.ml.automl import HyperparamBuilder, DiscreteHyperParam, GridSpace

#Define your hyperparameter 
gbt = <your gradient boosting tree estimator>
paramGrid = HyperparamBuilder().addHyperparam(gbt, gbt.maxBin, DiscreteHyperParam([200, 255, 300]))
```

Convert your `HyperparamBuilder` object into a format that the `GridSpace` constructor

```
>pa_val = {param.name: values for param, values in paramGrid.paramDict.items()}
ser_sp = GridSpace(list(pa_val.items()))
print(ser_sp)
```